# ¿Como obtener el valor de un dato sql si el dato en la tabla no es una foránea?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la tabla **usuario** la cual básicamente tiene `id, nombre_usuario, apellido_usuario, numero_identificación_usuario` y tengo la tabla **detalle_encuesta** la cual tiene `id, id_encuestado, descripcion_encuesta, fecha_realizada, identificación_encuestador`...

La columna llamada `identificación_encuestador` de  la tabla **detalle_encuesta** `NO es una FK` por motivo de que 'el dia' que se quiera eliminar ese detalle se elimina sin problema alguna, por ese motivo no es FK y porque ademas ya tiene una FK usuario que es el id del encuestado `(id_encuestado)`...

(se podria decir que `detalle_id_encuestado` e `identificación_encuestador` provienen de la misma tabla usuario pero no vale redundar con foraneas en una misma tabla)

**PROBLEMA**

Ahora lo que intento realizar es lo siguiente, una sentencia que me muestre todo el detalle_encuesta pero que de igual manera me muestre el nombre del encuestador que pertenezca a ese numero de indentifiacion...

Espero haberme hecho entender y dejo la setencia que intente realizar pero que aun no me funciona..

**SENTENCIA**

```
SELECT 
 identificacion_encuestador = (SELECT nombre_usuario
                   FROM usuario
                  WHERE 
                  numero_identificación_usuario = identificacion_encuestador),
  fecha_realizada,
  descripcion_encuesta
FROM
 detalle_encuesta,
  INNER JOIN usuario ON (detalle_id_encuestado = usuario_id )
WHERE
 detalle_id_encuestado = 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No importa que no sea foreign key igualmente se puede hacer join con la tabla, lo único que debes hacer es realizar el join con la tabla usuario  2 veces de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT 
 B.nombre_usuario as Encuestador,
  C.fecha_realizada,
  C.descripcion_encuesta,
A.nombre_usuario as Encuestado
FROM
 detalle_encuesta C,
  INNER JOIN usuario A ON C.detalle_id_encuestado = A.usuario_id 
  INNER JOIN usuario B ON C.identificacion_encuestador= B.usuario_id 
WHERE
 C.detalle_id_encuestado = 3
```

Answer (score 6):

No importa que no sea *foreign key*, igual se puede hacer `join` por ese campo.

```
SELECT encuestador.nombre_usuario, fecha_realizada, descripcion_encuesta, ...
FROM detalle_encuesta,
    INNER JOIN usuario as encuestado ON (detalle_id_encuestado = usuario_id)
    INNER JOIN usuario as encuestador ON (identificación_encuestador = usuario_id)
WHERE detalle_id_encuestado = 3
```

Ahora... ninguna de los motivos por los cuáles no tienes el campo `identificación_encuestador` como *foreign key* son válidos... Aunque esté como *foreign key* se puede borrar el registro, y no hay problema en tener más de una *foreign key* a la misma tabla. Te sugiero que revises tu modelo.